# How to send an email in PHP to a user ONLY IF one field is updated

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have figured out how to send an email in PHP if any change is done to the table at all.  Using a hook file that creates a function AFTER UPDATE.   However now I want to limit the emails to only when a change is made on one specific field.

The table name is 'compliance' and the field that I want it to send the email if changed is called 'Active'   So here is where I am at but I am dead in the water on the syntax of IF UPDATE.. ?? that line has a syntax error and I am not sure how to do it better.  Any assistance is welcome.

Here is the original code that works to send emails after all updates and even updates a database table with a record of the change so I have an audit trail now too:

```
function compliance_after_update($data, $memberInfo, &$args){

global $old_data;

foreach($data as $field => $value){
$messageData .= "$field: $value \n";
}
$recID=mysql_insert_id();
sql("insert into membership_userrecords set tableName='compliance' , pkValue='#recID', 
memberID=' ".getLoggedMemberID()."', dateAdded=' ".time()."', dateUpdated='".time()."',
groupID= ".getLoggedGroupID().".", $eo);

@mail(
// mail recipient
"email1, email2, email3",

// subject
"A Record in the Driver Compliance table of the database was changed - notification - Driver RECORD NUMBER-{$data['Record_Id']}",

// message
      "The above record {$data['Record_Id']} was just modified by:{$memberInfo['username']} The record was updated on and by:{$data['LastUpdatedby']} \n To view the record please go to \n http://domainname.com/appfoldername/compliance_view.php?SelectedID=".$data['selectedID']."  Newly entered data shows as actual table values below:,
     {$messageData} \n.  The user that changed this record did so from IP Address: {$memberInfo['IP']}  \n\n", 


// sender address
"my admin email address goes here"
);
// Capture and log changes to compliance record into the Compliance History Log table
sql("INSERT INTO `Comp_Hist_Log` (`Com_Rec_Id`, `old_data`, `new_data`, `ChangedDate`, `ChangedBy`) VALUES('{$data['Record_Id']}', '{$CapoldData}', '{$messageData}', '{$data['LastUpdated']}', '{$memberInfo['username']}')", $eo);

    return TRUE;
```

---

Here is the code that I am having problems with below..

---

```
    IF UPDATE ({$data['Active']}) 
{
@mail(
// mail recipient
"my email address here",

// subject
"A Driver Compliance Status has changed-{$data['Name']}",

// message
         "The above record {$data['Record_Id']} was just modified by: {$memberInfo['username']} The record was updated on and by user id: {$data['LastUpdatedby']},\n. To view the record please go to \n http://bigschoolbus.com/asdata2/compliance_view.php?SelectedID=".$data['selectedID']."  Newly entered data shows as actual table values below:,
     {$messageData}  The user that changed this record did so from IP Address: {$memberInfo['IP']} \n\n", 

// sender address
"my admin email address here"
);
    return TRUE;
```

---

Any advice?

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: what are you getting as error..?

Comment: No error message at all.. in dreamweaver the first line IF UPDATE.. is red as if it has a syntax error and the code when tested does not limit the emails if a different field is changed it still sends it.

Comment: I wish it did show an error message.. I am sure I just have it coded wrong.. just not sure how to code that part right.. the email part is fine.. the IF expression is the problem.  I want it to only send the email if compliance.Active changes from TRUE to FALSE or FALSE to TRUE.  If that field changes I want the email to send.. otherwise no email.  I know because of where I am putting the code that it will happen after the update to the record happens.. it now does send the email no matter what fields are changed.

Comment: It is easy when you want to perform an action based on if A==B but in this case I want to know when A is changed to B.. how do I code that part?

Comment: ANYONE??? really, this seems like it should be simple.. the "if update{$data['Active']} is where I have the problem.. this code is not proper PHP.. not sure in PHP how to do this.. anyone?  I have read four php manuals and nothing really shows me how to do it.  I just want to run the @mail part if the field Active is updated from FALSE to TRUE or from TRUE to FALSE, when it is actually updated?  Is there a way to do this?  There has to be?? Anyone??